# Как использовать константы в xml файле?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

В xml файле прописаны константные значение "1", "0", "-2" для orientation, width, height, например **android:orientation="1"**, **android:layout_width="2"**.

Но Эклипс ругается на такие записи (integer types not allowed).
Как правильно использовать эти константы?

Answer (score 1):

Как и написано в ошибке, вы не можете использовать integer.

Для задания размеров вам нужно указать размер в нужных единицах px, dp и т.д.

```
android:layout_width="100dp"
```

Для атрибута `android:orientation` нужно указать ориентацию которую вы хотите использовать `vertical` или `horizontal`

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```